# Can I play PS3 Saves from one PS3 on another?

Tags: ps3

I'm going home for Christmas and I was thinking of playing some of my PS3 games on my brother's PS3.

I know you can backup saves to a USB drive, but can I then upload these saves to my brother's PS3 and use them? Or are the saves locked to particular machine?

I know I'll have to login to the PSN with the same account.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some PlayStation 3 games have locked game-saves which means their game-saves are tied to the system itself. The result is that if you backup these files in a USB or an external HDD, you won't be able to use them in another system. (This is most likely done through encryption).

[Here's a list of games with locked game-saves](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/general-ps3-discussion/62819-ps3ts-official-locked-saved-games-thread.html). As the list states, games without *asterisks* have files which are locked to the system.

However, there's a way to bring these locked game-save to another system. The [PlayStation Plus service](http://playstationplus.com/main/index.html) lets you upload these files to Sony's servers to be able to retrieve them in other systems. This service is not free.

Comment: It's a shame that the list of games doesn't include the game I'm interested in... Up-vote for the answer though.